# Get contents of a web directory with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Say I have a web dir `someserver.com/json/` that has **directory listing enabled**.

And say in that directory I have several `<vcenter name>` directories.

And say that in each `someserver.com/<vcenter name>` directory there is a bunch of JSON files.

Assuming that my AngularJS app is running on `someserver.com`.

Is there a way in angularJS to get a listing of the `vcenter dirs` and json files within?

I plan to build an web app that parses info from all the JSON files and formats them into individual tables.